# UIImage resizes in custom UITableView on reloaddata

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage

I have a tableview with custom cells and I am adding some data to its as below:

```
{

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"black_lab_tideat2b.jpg"];

UIImageView *petPic = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:101];

UILabel *petName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];

petName.text = [current petName];

}
```

This data shows correctly in the UITableView.

The issue occurs when I attempt to delete a row using commitEditingStyle. After I have deleted the selected record from sqlite and do a

```
{
[self.tblListProfiles reloadData];
}
```

it resizes the image in the remaining cells. This resized image changes back to normal size after I add a new record to the sql and refresh using

```
{
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Can you please help?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your delegate for your UITableView implements `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` or has the `rowHeight` property set to the correct size.

[UITableViewDelegate reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a)

[UITableView reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks but the height of the table remains the same as before. The image actually goes outside the cell boundary.

Comment: Thanks. It was an error in my code. All fixed. Thanks for your help